# how to run a client and a server (w/ sockets) on python in mac?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, sockets

i've build a very basic client

```
import socket
my_socket = socket.socket()
my_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8820))
message = raw_input()
my_socket.send(message)
my_socket.close()
```

and a server

```
import socket

server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8820))

server_socket.listen(1)

(client_socket, client_address) = server_socket.accept()

client_name = client_socket.recv(1024)
client_socket.send('Hello ' + client_name + '!')

client_socket.close()
server_sockrt.close()
```

in windows i run them through cmd, how to run them on mac? thanks for help.

Comment: Also through terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Hit `Cmd-Space` and enter `term` then hit Enter. This should open a Mac terminal window. By default the Python will be 2.7, which should work with your code.

Comment: Note that `Cmd+Space` is called a *"Spotlight search"* and it enables you to look for Applications (such as **Terminal**), files, Contacts, websites etc.

Comment: But how to get to my files to run them through terminal?

Comment: it says -bash: /cyber/server.py: Permission denied

Comment: Try `python /cyber/server.py`, or first add execute permissions with `chmod +x /cyber/server.py`.

Comment: it won't send anything, just hop on to next line

Answer (score 1):

Save the following file as `server.py` in your HOME directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket

server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8820))

server_socket.listen(1)

(client_socket, client_address) = server_socket.accept()

client_data = client_socket.recv(1024)
print("Received: %s" % client_data)
client_socket.send('Hello ' + client_data + '!')

client_socket.close()
server_socket.close()
```

Save the following as `client.py` in your HOME directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket
my_socket = socket.socket()
my_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8820))
message = raw_input('Enter some data: ')
my_socket.send(message)
response_data = my_socket.recv(1024)
print("Received: %s" % response_data)
my_socket.close
```

---

Start **Terminal**, by hitting <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>SPACE</kbd> and typing "Terminal" followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Make both the scripts executable by running the following command once (it changes their mode by adding the `x` executable bit):

```
chmod +x *py
```

Now run the server with:

```
./server.py
```

Now press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>, to get a New Terminal and in the new Terminal type:

```
./client.py
```

And everything should work.

The first line of each script is called a *"shebang"* in Unix if you want to learn about it.